# Xcode build fails. Xcode crashes on clicking mainStoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

Build fails for running (every) iOS project only. Succeed's for other For Eg: Command line tool application. Also when I click on MainStoryBoard the Xcode crashes.

My Xcode: Version 5.0 (5A1413) on OS X Yosemite Version 10.10

Getting two errors: 
(1)Command

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
>   failed with exit code 255

(2)

> /Users/sky/Desktop/xcode projects/SKY/SKY/Images.xcassets: The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error
>   1.)

Things I have tried. 
(1)I have tried Right click on Storyboard in the navigator -> Show File Inspector -> Uncheck "Use Autolayout". It does not solve. Please help!
(2)I have tried project cleaning cmd+Shit+K, Clean succeeded, Build Failed!

Comment: My Xcode: Version 5.0 (5A1413) on OS X Yosemite Version 10.10

Comment: @Varosion had checked that before posting, that thread did not help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Create a new project and check if the behaviour is the same. If Xcode doesn't crash on your new project, open your "problematic" project and go to the menu "Product" and then "Clean", that might fix the issue. That happens to me a lot with visual studio and eclipse. Hope you get it working, post the solution later please.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, installing latest version of Xcode (Xcode6) did solve the issue. (My older one was xcode5). Now all iOS projects run. I had a feeling upgrading should ideally solve the problem, but I wanted to work for that project on xcode5, hence I was looking for a solution. Thank you every one for help.